# cannot access session in include file ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have an Ajax script like this, that includes a file to process that is getvar.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".jenisdata").change(function() {
            var jenisdata =$(this).val();

            var dataString = 'jenisdata='+jenisdata;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "includes/analisis/getvar.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $(".variabel").html(html);
                } 
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and the getvar.php to get the variable passing from Ajax is like this:

```
<?php
include ('../../../config/config.php');

$id_user=$_SESSION['id_user'];
if($_POST['jenisdata']) {
    $id= $_POST['jenisdata'];
    $query      = "SELECT var.id_var, var.nama_var
FROM var, hak_akses
WHERE var.id_var = hak_akses.id_var
AND id_user ='$id_user' AND id_data ='$id'";
    $results    = mysql_query( $query);
    $total      = mysql_num_rows($results);

    if ($total >0) {
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
                echo '<option     value="'.$rows['id_var'].'">'.$rows['nama_var'].'</option>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<option value="" selected="selected">Data variabel belum diisi     dijenisdata Ini</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

The variable `$_SESSION['id_user']` cannot be read here. What's the problem, and how can I get the session within the Ajax included file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include `session_start();` anytime you wanna use session variables

Like so...

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('../../../config/config.php');


//rest of your code

?>
```

That is....assuming you have set the $_SESSION['id_user'] at an earlier time, and it does infact exist...

Answer (score 0):

try echoing you Session variable and see what's returning, but of course first make sure to start the session as KyleK said.  Also it will do no harm to validate if the session variable is set.